# href not working in navigation bar...can someone tell me how to make it work

Tags: javascript, html, css

css

```
.b1 {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.ls
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:165px;
}
.p1
{
    position:absolute;
    left:55px;
    top:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:200px;
}
.p2
{
    position:absolute;
    left:500px;
    top:400px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:200px;
}
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
    float:left;
}
li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.active
{
    background-color:burlywood;
}
```

html

- Home
  Veg
- Non-Veg
- Desserts
- Beverages

```
    <script>
        var myVeg=document.getElementById('myveg');
        myVeg.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                window.location.href='Veg_1.html';
            });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: ul
            {
                
                list-style-type:none;
                background-color:#000000;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                
                
            }

Comment: .b1
            {
                background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }
            .ls
            {
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:165px;
            }
            .p1
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:55px;
                top:0px;
                margin:0px;
                padding:200px;
            }
            .p2
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:500px;
                top:400px;
                margin:0px;
                padding:200px;
            }

Comment: It worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/xcsfpgbm/

Answer (score 1):

You have set the ID to the `li`. Try to set the ID to the `a` itself. In that way your JS knows when a user clicked on the href.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#veg" id="myveg">Veg</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Non-Veg" >Non-Veg</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Desserts" >Desserts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Bevereges" >Beverages</a></li>
</ul>
```